# how can I specify that an input parameter depends on another parameter

Tags: java, spring, rest, parameters, spring-restdocs

In my Rest Service i could have request country parameter by two way
On in subOject from main User Object and an other way friendly is country code in String
Could i in Spring RestsDocs says if firendly country Code is not exist subobject is necessary ?
Regards

I just want viewing in documentation that subobject country is necessary if friendly country code not exist

Comment: Add some code, and review your question. It is hard to understand what you are in for.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.